# How can I redirect a webpage to a php generated frame without repeating the frame in itself?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, iframe

**My problem:**

I have a webpage with the the following structure:

```
localhost/redirect_test/umleitungs_verzeichnis/index.php
```

If I go to any address in this directory or below this folder, like

```
localhost/redirect_test/umleitungs_verzeichnis/sub2/
```

I want all the sites there to be redirected into a frame.

**My solution so far:**

There is now a htaccess in the first directory:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/redirect_test/umleitungs_verzeichnis/(.*)$     [NC]
# ...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/redirect_test/frame_seite.php?url=$1 [L,R=301]
```

so I'll be redirected to a php-script which puts the url that has been called into a frame.

**The php-script looks like:**

```
<?php

//receive URL via GET from htaccess
(isset($_GET["url"])) ? ($getUrl = $_GET["url"]) : ($getUrl = "");

// create path for redirection
$url = "http://localhost/redirect_test/umleitungs_verzeichnis". "/" .  $getUrl;

// generate HTML
...
$output .= "<iframe src=\"" .$url. "\" width=\"100%\"  height=\"850px\" />\r\n</iframe>\r\n\r\n";
...

// display HTML
echo $output;

?>
```

My problem is that the redirection won't end, because the url in the frame jumps into the directory where it will be redirected to the script which generates the frame.

Since I'm a htaccess newby I have no clue what to do.
I thought about a rule that would avoid the redirection if one is redirected from the script but nothing worked.

**So does somebody know how**

1. to break the redirect-rule so I'm only redirected once, OR
2. how I can get any site into a frame when I land in a certain folder or any of its subfolders.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well the server can not differentiate between those two requests, they look the same to it. So one easy way around this would be to add an additional GET parameter to the iframe source URL, so that these two requests _become_ different requests, and you can check for whether that additional GET parameter was is present or not, before you redirect.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I added RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^script=true$ and a parameter in the URL. The frame now shows the single page in the frame. But for every click to a sub page a new frame is opened. I have to 'break' through each last frame, then I can post the answer.

Comment: That is again the problem, that the server has no way to differentiate between the requests. It does not know anything about imaginary client-side constructs like “frames” - _if_ you want it to be able to differentiate between those, then _you_ need to make them different in the first place. (For example by creating all links inside those iframed documents dynamically, so that if the document gets loaded into an iframe to begin with, all links get that same parameter appended as well.)

Comment: My problem is, I don't want to change all the documents called into the frames. That's exactly what I want to avoid. Since I've got almost no experience in htaccess-configuration I wondered if someone already had that problem. I'm sure some experienced person would find the solution pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

in the .htaccess file and moved it one path up.